# How to select join multiple table without conditional in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select multiple table using join in codeigniter but I don't want to make any conditional as below code

```
public function get_invoice(){

    $this->db->select('isp.*,dp.*,ip.*'); 
    $this->db->from('isp');
    $this->db->join('dp','dp.status = isp.status');
    $this->db->join('isp','isp.status = ip.status');
    $this->db->limit(5000);
    $this->query =  $this->db->get();
    if($this->query->num_rows()>0){
        return $this->query->result();
    }

}
```

however I want to get all data in that table without conditional but in join statement have to used conditional.

**So how can I select data from multiple table without conditional in codeigniter?**

Thanks for help

Comment: Your number of records of the query can be zero in case of no records in the given criteria. Then what do you want?

Comment: It would not work what I want to select data from 3 table and have not conditional. So do you have any sql option that let me select or not or I have to used join ?

Comment: You can use left join.

Comment: I don't know something wrong my row of two table have only 8rows but when I select it show 16 rows. make me crazy now

`$this->db->select('*'); 
  $this->db->from('dp');
  $this->db->join('isp','isp.status = dp.status','left');
  $this->query =  $this->db->get();
  return $this->query->result(); `

Comment: @CootelKh, since the question is not that explanatory, can you provide an example output? How should the output dataset(s) look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can join query without condition. INNER LEFT RIGHT JOINS need condition.So you can do Cross JOIN.LIKE this

```
public function get_invoice(){

 $this->db->select('isp.*,dp.*,ip.*'); 
 $this->db->from('isp,dp,ip');
 $this->db->limit(5000);
 $this->query =  $this->db->get();
 if($this->query->num_rows()>0)
 {
    return $this->query->result();
 }

}
```

But at Cross JOIN if your isp has 100,dp has 20, and ip has 50 record It will produce (100*20*50) record.I hope you know what CROSS,LEFT,INNER,RIGHT JOIN do.

Comment: I'm no mind for someone vote me down but if you are a respond person you should keep some commend let me know some reason why you have to vote down@!!!!!!

Comment: Yes I'm really thanks for your help but have someone vote down bong I also don't know who too