# how to search a keyword from multiple tables from database and there is no common field to JOIN table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to search a keyword in different tables if result available then  I need to return that row of data to Codeigniter `controller.my` model function is below:

```
public function get_search($match) 
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('blog.blog_title',$match);
$this->db->like('casestudy.title',$match);
$this->db->from('blog,casestudy');
$query = $this->db->get();
print_r($this->db->last_query()); exit;
return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: check this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27101784/4464010

Comment: I want to search a keyword and if the keyword matches any column then I get that row result also.plz help

Comment: $this->db->select('blog.*,casestudy.*,career.*'); 
 $this->db->from('blog,casestudy,career');
 $this->db->like('blog_title', $match);
 $this->db->limit(5000);
 $this->query =  $this->db->get();
 print_r($this->db->last_query()); exit;
 if($this->query->num_rows()>0)
 {
    return $this->query->result();

 }

Comment: get many rows repeatedly. I need only row where keyword present

Comment: avoid duplicates using group by column

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no relation between the two tables, it may not make sense to do a join, and what you are currently doing is a cross join.  Instead, consider taking a union of the two tables:

```
$first = DB::table('blog')
            ->where('blog_title', 'like', '%' . $match . '%')

$second = DB::table('casestudy')
             ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $match . '%')
             ->unionAll($first)
             ->get();
```

This answer assumes that you want to do `SELECT *` from each table, which in turn implies that the columns of both tables have the same type and ordering.  If this be not the case, then you can refine what I wrote above by selecting particular columns which you want to be a part of the union query.

For the sake of readability, the raw query I have in mind is this:

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%'.$match.'%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM casestudy WHERE title LIKE '%'.$match.'%';
```

Comment: Sir its not working for me .  
I want to search a keyword and if the keyword matches any column then I get that row result also.plz help –

Comment: Of course your question is not answerable because we have no idea what your tables look like.  In any case, I have answered your original question as you wrote it.